# Query elements of a list inside a dictionary of certain type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary with a key and values as a list with my class StructureData.

```
private readonly Dictionary<IntBound, List<StructureData>> structuresDataCollection;
```

NatureStructureData is a child of StructureData.

I need to check for IntBound with NatureStructureData and without it for a selected IntBound. I know to check for a first element, but I need to check all elements in a list. How to rewrite these expressions to check all elements inside each list?

```
public IEnumerable<IntBound> GetBoundsWithStructuresWithoutNatureWithin(IntBound selectionBounds)
{
    return structuresDataCollection
        .Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(selectionBounds))
        .Where(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault() is not NatureStructureData)
        .Select(s => s.Key);
}

public IEnumerable<IntBound> GetBoundsWithNatureWithin(IntBound selectionBounds)
{
    return structuresDataCollection
        .Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(selectionBounds))
        .Where(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault() is NatureStructureData)
        .Select(s => s.Key);
}
```

Comment: How about `s.Value.OfType<NatureStructureData>().Any()`

Comment: @Oliver thank you, so we have a following expression: structuresDataCollection.Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(selectionBounds)).Where(s => s.Value.OfType<NatureStructureData>().Any()).Select(s => s.Key);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach should be similar to the your previous question, but combined with `Any`:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IntBound> GetBoundsWithStructuresWithoutNatureWithin(IntBound selectionBounds)
{
    return structuresDataCollection
        .Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(selectionBounds))
        .Where(s => !s.Value.OfType<NatureStructureData>().Any())
        .Select(s => s.Key);
}

public IEnumerable<IntBound> GetBoundsWithNatureWithin(IntBound selectionBounds)
{
    return structuresDataCollection
        .Where(s => s.Key.Intersects(selectionBounds))
        .Where(s => s.Value.OfType<NatureStructureData>().Any())
        .Select(s => s.Key);
}
```

To get more familiar with LINQ I recommend:

- [linqsamples.com](https://linqsamples.com/)
- [LINQ Pocket Reference by Albahari](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linq-pocket-reference/9780596519247/)